# How can I host SSL applications on public Cloud Foundry?

Tags: cloud-foundry

I have read a lot of blogs and support forums about modifying the nginx configurations for obtaining SSL access to application but how can we do the same on public CF? I want to be able to do this on public cloud space of CF and not on micro cloud foundry.

Regards,

Kinjal

Comment: Hi Kinjal. What have you tried so far?

Comment: http://docs.cloudfoundry.com/docs/using/managing-apps/custom-domains/cloudflare.html

Answer (score 1):

You can access any application hosted on cloudfoundry.com via http and https.

Comment: Hi Dan,Thanks a lot for the reply. How and where can I upload certificates in that case?

Comment: cloudfoundry.com currently does not support custom domain names, so the apps that you deploy reside under *.cloudfoundry.com and as Dan answered, you can already use https if you so desire. Note that Cloud Foundry will support custom domain names at some point.

Comment: Hi Dan, Eric,Thanks a lot for the replies. I understand that using https also connects the application via http internally in CF. In this case how will we migrate application that require authentication credentials? Asking since such credentials would then be unencrypted.

Comment: @KinjalDoshi https://github.com/cloudfoundry-collaboration/vcap/wiki/Setup-SSL-on-cloudfoundry-landscape helps?